# Laravel variable variable is not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have two variables, which are same but localized. And i also have a $locale variable, which is holding locale appendix (_en etc..)

Now i want to combine them and create variable variable to print proper localized variable.

```
{{${'$v->fuel_type->vehicle_fuel_type'}.$locale}}
```

But i get error Undefined variable: $v->fuel_type->vehicle_fuel_type_en (View: /var/www/html/sixt/resources/views/offerselect-new.blade.php)

But there is $v->fuel_type->vehicle_fule_type variable. What's wrong with this?

Comment: Take the single quotes out

Comment: What is the format of the variable that you're trying to generate?

Comment: @aynber json object?

Comment: Try `{{ $v->fuel_type->${'vehicle_fuel_type' . $locale} }}`

Comment: @Robert same error... vehicle_fuel_type_en undefined

Comment: Can you post the output of `dd($v->fuel_type);` ?

Comment: @Robert {#622 ▼
  +"vehicle_fuel_type_en": "Gasoline"
  +"id": 1
  +"vehicle_fuel_type": "Benzin"
}

Comment: Do `{{ data_get($v, "fuel_type.vehicle_fuel_type".($locale?"_".$locale:"")) }}`

Comment: @apokryfos thanks it works. Please answer it i will accept

Comment: @yigitozmen and just using `{{ $v->fuel_type->vehicle_fuel_type_en }}` works?

Comment: @Robert yes it works statically by the way apokryfos 's answer is right for me

Comment: @yigitozmen ok... but that means _ is not set in `$locale`

Comment: @Robert yes i have manuplated for my problem, but it's generally proper answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the (hardly documented) laravel helper [`data_get`](http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/laravel/framework/source-function-data_get.html#380-421)  would make things a lot easier for you:

```
{{ data_get($v, "fuel_type.vehicle_fuel_type".($locale?"_".$locale:"")) }}
```

This is similar to [`array_get`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-array-get) but also works for objects.